# how to close connection after running cuteFTP .vbs script?

Tags: file-upload, vbscript, ftp

we are using the macro record facility available in cuteFTP to generate a vbs file which we use to upload a local copy of the database to Godaddy.

How do we go about closing the connection on upload completion as if we do not there is a risk that the file is locked and causes the website to fall over? Is there a better way to do this?

thanks for any pointers

```
' Create TEConnection object
Set MySite = CreateObject("CuteFTPPro.TEConnection")

' Initialize remote server host name, protocol, port, etc.
MySite.Host = "ftp.servername.here"
MySite.Protocol = "FTP"
MySite.Port = 21
MySite.Retries = 30
MySite.Delay = 30
MySite.MaxConnections = 4
MySite.TransferType = "AUTO"
MySite.DataChannel = "DEFAULT"
MySite.AutoRename = "OFF"
' WARNING!!! SENSITIVE DATA: user name and password.
MySite.Login = "username"
MySite.Password = "password"
MySite.SocksInfo = ""
MySite.ProxyInfo = ""
' Connect to remote server
MySite.Connect
MySite.UploadAsync "C:\Projects\access_db\propertyDB.mdb", "/access_db/propertyDB.mdb"
```

Comment: I would look at the `Close()` method passing the `"EXITNOPENDING"` option in the [Official Documentation](https://help.globalscape.com/help/cuteftp9/#t=Methods_properties_and_wildcards.htm).

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the [Official Documentation](https://help.globalscape.com/help/cuteftp9/#t=TOC_Transfer_Engine.htm) suggests you could use the `Close()` method and pass the `"EXITNOPENDING"` option as an argument.

From the [Official Documentation](https://help.globalscape.com/help/cuteftp9/#t=Methods_properties_and_wildcards.htm):

> ##### Close
>
> Use the Close method to exit the Transfer Engine. You can include parameters to exit only on certain conditions.
>
> ###### Syntax
>
> ```
> Object.Close (BSTR bstrParameter)
> ```
>
> ###### Parameters
>
> ""(default empty), "CLOSE", "EXIT"—Closes TE (all tasks will be stopped)
> "EXITNOPENDING"—Closes TE if no pending tasks available
>
> ###### Example
>
> ```vb
> Set MySite = CreateObject("CuteFTPPro.TEConnection")
> MySite.LocalFolder = "c:\temp"
> MySite.TransferURLAsync "ftp://ftp.cuteftp.com/pub/cuteftp"
> MySite.Close "EXITNOPENDING"
> ```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond. unfortunately that did not quite fix the problem so it must be something else :(